# (QML) What does the "?" do in defining properties?

Tags: application-development, programming, ubuntu-sdk, qml, qt-creator

```
Popey {
working: visible ? 100
}
```

What does that **"?"** indicate in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet of code in your question does not work for me. I wrote a minimal example:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

MainView {
    width: units.gu(48)
    height: units.gu(60)
    id: mainView

    Rectangle {
        height: visible ? 20;
        width: 20;
    }

}
```

And `qmlscene` reports the following error:

```
qmlscene ./foo.qml 
file:///home/sylvain/foo.qml:10 Expected token `:'
```

The correct syntax for the javascript [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323829/javascript-ternary-operator-example-with-functions) is as follow:

```
height: visible ? 20 : 10;
```

Comment: Ah the Colon! That was my second question. I guess it goes with the question mark then.

Comment: Indeed both are actually making up the operator

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx -- just what I needed. Thanks Sylvain

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp, why msdn ;)